# How do I say "Humanism" in Latin?

Tags: classical-latin, ancient-greek, philosophy-terms

Humanism is coined from a Latin root (homo, hominis) and a Greek suffix (-ισμός).
Would there be a "purely Latin" translation of this word?

Comment: Wouldn't "humanitas" work?

Answer (score 6):

English *humanism* (or more precisely, Italian *umanesimo*) is effectively a calque of (Cicero's conception of) *hūmānitās*, which itself is *hūmānus* (not *homō*, though the words must be related) +‎ the abstract noun suffix *-tās*, swapping out the original Latin ending for a different abstract noun suffix to avoid confusion with the already existing word *humanity* (*umanità*). You could use *hūmānitās* to refer to humanism, but the same issue exists in Latin as in English and Italian: the primary, obvious meaning of *hūmānitās* is just 'humanity'.

You could look for a different Latin abstract noun suffix to substitute, but I don't think there's actually anything wrong with ***hūmānismus***: the Greek suffix -ισμός was borrowed moderately productively into Latin as *-ismus* already in the Late Latin period, and it's undeniably productive in humanist Neo-Latin. You're not adding a Greek suffix to a Latin word so much as adding a Neo-Latin suffix to create a Neo-Latin word, and one that—unlike the alternatives—is instantly transparent.

Comment: From what I remember, using humanitas for humanity isn't considered good Latin. Things like gens humana or genus humanum or even universitas humana. That would make humanism seem like a pretty good primary meaning of humanitas, with parallels in things like romanitas and latinitas.